# Jacobian of the Jacobian of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

## Minimal Working Example

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. It's Jacobian function is $J_f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. What is the Jacobian of its Jacobian function?

Intuitively, it should be
$$
J_{J_f}:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{(m\times n) \times n }
$$
and so evaluating at a point should give $J_{J_f}(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n \times n}$. Which I guess is a rank $3$ tensor. What is the property of this tensor? Intuitively, I feel like it should be able to take two $n\times 1$ vectors and return a $m\times 1$ vector?

## Context

Basically in my context I know that I need this tensor thing to have some sort of bilinearity in the sense that it takes two $n\times 1$ vectors and return a $m\times 1$ vector?

$$
J_{J_f}(a_1, a_2)[x] 
$$

Or perhaps it can take two $n\times m$ matrices and return a vector? I am so confused. The only way in which I could make it work is if it takes $n\times m \times 1$ matrices (whose transpose is has to be $(1\times n\times m)$ for things to work out) and then the dimensions work out because
$$
(1\times n\times m) \times (m\times n\times n) \times (n\times m\times 1) = 1\times n\times n\times m \times 1 = 1 \times m \times 1 = m\times 1
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is is misleading to write $J_f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Actually the range is $M(m,n;\mathbb R)$, the vector space of all real $m \times n$-matrices. You may indentify $M(m,n;\mathbb R)$ with $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, but this reveals what $J_f$ "really" does.

More formally let $\mathcal L(V,W)$ denote the set of $\mathbb R$-linear maps between real vector spaces $V, W$. It is a real vector space of dimension $\dim V \cdot \dim W$. Then the derivative of $f$ is a map
$$df : \mathbb R^n \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m) .$$
With respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m$ the linear map $df(x) = df\mid_x$ is represented by the Jacobian matrix $J_f$ at $x$.

Now $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m)$ is a finite-dimensional normed linear space. A norm can be introduced via any linear isomorphism $\phi : \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m) \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. But the choice of a norm is irrelevant because all norms on finite-dimensional  vector spaces are equivalent.

We can form the derivative of $df$ and get a map
$$d^2f  = ddf :  \mathbb R^n \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m)) .$$
By some elementary (multi-)linear algebra we see that $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m))$ can be identified with the vector space of bilinear maps $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ from
$\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$. The identification goes by associating to $L \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m))$, which is a linear map $L : \mathbb R^n \to  \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m)$), the bilinear map $\alpha(L) : \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ given by
$$\alpha(L)(v,w) = L(v)(w) .$$
It is easily verified that $\alpha : \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n ,\mathbb R^m)) \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ is a vector space isomorphism. We can therefore regard

$$\bar d^2f = \alpha \circ d^2f :  \mathbb R^n \to L(\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m) $$
as an alternative representation of $d^2f$. You see that $\bar d^2f(x)$ is what you expected.

Iterating this, we see that we can regard the $r$-th derivative of $f$ as a map
$$\bar d^r f: \mathbb R^n \to L(\mathbb R^n \times \ldots \times \mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m) $$
with range being the vector space of all multilinear maps from the $r$-fold product of copies of $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: Thank you so much for going in depth and being precise. I read through your answer a few times but I am still quite confused. Mainly as to how this would work in practice. From what I understand $d^2f$ and $\overline{d}^2f$ are two different representations of the Jacobian of the Jacobian of $f$.  The first one takes in a $n\times 1$ vector and outputs a linear map that takes an $n\times 1$ vector and maps it to a $n\times m$ matrix. Is that right?

Comment: So if I have vectors $v_1, v_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $d^2f(v_1)$ is a map that given $v_2$ as input it outputs $(d^2 f(v_1))(v_2)$ which is an $n\times m$ matrix. I suppose instead of writing $(d^2 f(v_1))(v_2)$ I could write $d^2 f(v_1, v_2)$ which is a matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct. But my approach does not use matrix representations of linear maps. If you want to work with matrices, I suggest to use the word "column vector" instead of "$(n \times 1)$-vector". The original $d^2f$ takes each column vector in $\mathbb R^n$ to an $(n \times m)$-matrix. This matrix associates to each column vector in $\mathbb R^n$ a column vector in $\mathbb R^m$. The modified $\bar d^2f$ takes a pair of column vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ to a column vector in $\mathbb R^m$.  As you say, $d^2f(v_1)(v_2) = \bar d^2f(v_1,v_2)$.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am back again on this question because I am a bit confused, it would be amazing if you could help. In my problem I can't use index notation, so am trying to use somewhat a "matrix" notation, even though we are working with tensors.

Basically I am trying to figure out how to use the "bilinearity" properties.

Comment: For example, say $H_X(v, w)$ is the Hessian tensor at $x$ taking column vectors $v$ and $w$. Can I factor out matrices?
$$
H_x(Av, w) = AH_x(v, w)
$$
This is an $n\times n$ matrix and I don't think this operation is well-defined. Similarly, say I only give it one vector, can I still take out the matrix?
$$
H_x(Av, \cdot) = A H_x(v, \cdot)
$$
Basically $H_x(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a third-order tensor. When I give it two vectors it outputs an $m$-dimensional vector. When I give it one vector, I think it outputs a matrix?

Comment: For full context, I have the function 
$$
N(x) = J_f(x)^\top (J_f(x) J_f(x)^\top)^{-1} J_f(x) 
$$
which is basically an orthogonal projection. One could equally write $N(x) = J_f(x)^+ J_f(x)$ where $J_f(x)^+$ is the pseudo-inverse. I have found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2156365.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A26c368550a0572d662d4cda4b1445ddb&ab_segments=&origin=&acceptTC=1) that the derivative of $N(x)$ is given by (see Corollary 4.2)
$$
DN_x = J_f(x) H_x (I - N(x)) + (J_f(x) H_x (I - N(x)))^\top
$$

Comment: and now I am basically trying to figure out what happens when I apply the third-order tensor $DN_x$, and how I use bilinearity. For instance, what happens when I have
$$
DN_x(Av + Bw, \cdot)
$$
Can use linearity to write this?
$$
DN_x(Av, \cdot) + DN_x(Bw, \cdot)
$$
and how can I take out the matrices?

Comment: @Euler_Salter This is a completely new question. Comments are not adequate for that. Please ask a separate question and explain precisely in what situation your $H_x$ occurs. But I believe that I am not the right person to answer it.

Comment: That's true. But that's just context. All I want to know is how to handle this object algebraically.